# Cropping a picture with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, crop

Can please someone explain to me or bring me on the way how to crop a picture with JavaScript / jQuery?
I'm not looking for a plugin, I want to understand how it is done and use it.
I also don't want `div` manipulations with background positions.
I want to crop the actual picture. But only for client side purposes. I don't need a hook to the back end to save the cropped picture.

Comment: Where is your code?  Have you tried anything at all yet?  http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128553/157574

Comment: I can not try anything up to now, because I don't find any entry point.

Comment: Not wanting to use a plugin doesn't preclude you from looking at the source code of plugins.  So then [this](http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=jquery+crop+image&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) would be a good starting point.

Comment: Upon reading your question again, something doesn't make sense.  If you're not saving the final image anyplace, then what is wrong with a `div` manipulation using background position?  What possible difference would it make?  In fact, your accepted answer is using that method.

Comment: Yeah I have seen that before, they play with an image tag in a div and change the positions. I just wanted to know if it is possible to slice an image up and use the slices and I just don't find the functionality. But it seems that is the only way. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jQuery has no picture cropping functionality.

You could for example use the HTML5 canvas element to achieve that. Here's a [tutorial](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-image-crop/):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      body {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
      }
      #myCanvas {
        border: 1px solid #9C9898;
      }
    </style>
    <script>
      window.onload = function() {
        var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
        var imageObj = new Image();

        imageObj.onload = function() {
          // draw cropped image
          var sourceX = 150;
          var sourceY = 0;
          var sourceWidth = 150;
          var sourceHeight = 150;
          var destWidth = sourceWidth;
          var destHeight = sourceHeight;
          var destX = canvas.width / 2 - destWidth / 2;
          var destY = canvas.height / 2 - destHeight / 2;

          context.drawImage(imageObj, sourceX, sourceY, sourceWidth, sourceHeight, destX, destY, destWidth, destHeight);
        };
        imageObj.src = "http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/darth-vader.jpg";
      };

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="578" height="400"></canvas>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If jQuery, or even vanilla js has no crop function how do they do it in the sliders that slice the images into tiles for the transition?

Comment: Those aren't cropping the image, they are only displaying a portion of the image by either setting it as a backroung image and using the position, or by placing it in a div with overflow: hidden and moving it around within that div. The clip: css style may be used aswell.